# Populate Column A with TEXT before Splice

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following onEdit(e) Google Apps Script which populates columns A:D in the next row of another sheet. I now want it to populate columns B:E and in Column A of the same row to populate with the text "SOP":

```js
 {
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var sourcesheetname = "SOP Register"
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var editedColumn = range.getColumn();
  var editedRow = range.getRow();
  var column = 7;
  var date = range.getValue();
  if(Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]' && editedColumn == column && editedRow > 3 && sheet.getName() == sourcesheetname) {
    var targetsheetname = "Internal Audit Register";
    var target = e.source.getSheetByName(targetsheetname);
    var numCols = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var values = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numCols).getValues()[0];
    values.splice(7)
    values.splice(0, 0)
    values.splice(1, 0)
    values.splice(2, 3); // Removing undesired values
    var lastRow = target.getLastRow();
    var lastCol = target.getLastColumn();
    target.appendRow(values); // Append new row  
    sheet.hideColumns(6,2);
   }
}
```

Below is my Source Sheet:

[image: Source Data]

Below is the target sheet data after the script:

[image]

This is my desired outcome:

[image]

This is a sample of my spreadsheet. The script code starts at line 67.

[Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ar331lGrSe3AvR5D2uYdLhlybvvU-heXWP1Q4FwSZEM/edit?usp=sharing)

Just not sure how to do this.

Comment: Some images of your spreadsheet might be helpful.

Comment: @Cooper - I have added images

Comment: Please can you provide access to a sanitised copy of your sheet with an example of your desired output?

Comment: I have now added a sample of the spreadsheet and the desired outcome

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I have now added a sample of the spreadsheet and the desired outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Use `array.unshift()` to append the desired string to the beginning of the array before you append the row.*

#### More Information:

As per the MDN documentation:

> The unshift() method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array and returns the new length of the array.

So before you append your new row to your second sheet, you need to use `unshift()` to add the string `"SOP"` to the beginning:

```js
{
  // ...
  var lastRow = target.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = target.getLastColumn();
  values.unshift("SOP"); // << Add this
  target.appendRow(values); // Append new row  
  sheet.hideColumns(6,1);
  sheet.hideColumns(7,1);
}
```

#### References:

- [Array.prototype.unshift() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)